# ElementTree write function does not write to standard out

Tags: python, python-3.x, elementtree

I'm trying to output an XML structure to stdout with ElementTree. I'm trying with:

```
root = ET.Element('networkData')    
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write(sys.stdout)
```

but I get no output. Changing the argument to a string produces an XML file as expected. Using the debugger (adding encoding tip from SO) I get:

```
-> tree.write(sys.stdout, encoding='utf-8')
(Pdb) n
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Googling the error I get a few hits but none that seems to address this issue.
Also, I get confused by the error message as sys.stdout is a _io.TextIOWrapper object.

Comment: On python3? `tree.write(sys.stdout, encoding='unicode')` may work.

Comment: Or use `tree.write(sys.stdout.buffer)`.

Comment: According to https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/786, sys.stdout.buffer might not exist.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has to do with encoding. Without correct encoding, the argument is treated as binary and not as string, which explains the error message. The proper write-statement should be:

```
tree.write(sys.stdout, encoding='unicode')
```

or

```
tree.write(sys.stdout.buffer)
```

as pointed out in the comments.